# AWS sagemaker error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, docker, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

As per this - [How to use a pretrained model from s3 to predict some data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255154/how-to-use-a-pretrained-model-from-s3-to-predict-some-data) , I was trying to use an existing model to create an endpoint, but I was facing the following error -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 55, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 143, in handle_request
    super().handle_request(listener_name, req, sock, addr)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 106, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 124, in main
    serving_env.module_dir)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker_sklearn_container/serving.py", line 101, in import_module
    user_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 118, in import_module
    if name.startswith('.'):
```

As per [Problem deploying the best estimator gotten with sagemaker.estimator.Estimator (w/ sklearn custom image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050712/problem-deploying-the-best-estimator-gotten-with-sagemaker-estimator-estimator), https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=313838 , I am using the correct env variables (along with `SAGEMAKER_DEFAULT_INVOCATIONS_ACCEPT`, `SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM`, and `SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY`), but somehow the health checks are failing while creation of the endpoint.

I tried the similar thing via AWS console and it is working surprisingly.
Is there a work around for this to do it via code?

My code snippet:

```
trainedmodel = sagemaker.model.Model(
model_data='s3://my-bucket/my-key/output/model.tar.gz',
image='my-image',
env={"SAGEMAKER_DEFAULT_INVOCATIONS_ACCEPT": "text/csv", 
     "SAGEMAKER_USE_NGINX": "True", 
     "SAGEMAKER_WORKER_CLASS_TYPE": "gevent", 
     "SAGEMAKER_KEEP_ALIVE_SEC": "60", 
     "SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20",
     "SAGEMAKER_ENABLE_CLOUDWATCH_METRICS": "false",
     "SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM": "my-script.py",
     "SAGEMAKER_REGION": "us-east-1",
     "SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY": "s3://my-bucket/my-key/source/sourcedir.tar.gz"
    },
role=role)

trainedmodel.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', endpoint_name = 'my-endpoint')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else landing here, I had a similar issue when creating sklearn models from a ModelPackage.

Error message in endpoint logs when trying to create endpoint:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Solved with the following when defining the model package:

- Env variable `SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY` should be set to the directory on the container, normally `'/opt/ml/model/'`
- `SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM` should be set to the name of the serving script, e.g. 'sagemaker_serve.py'

These are specified under the 'Environment' section part of each entry in the 'Containers' section.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace, it looks like the container cannot find your entry_point module (my-script.py).

By default, the container will add `'opt/ml/code'` to the Python path and modules under this directory can be imported.

You can modify this path to other values by providing values to `SAGEMAKER_BASE_PATH` (default to `'/opt/ml'`) and put your script under `'<SAGEMAKER_BASE_PATH>/code'` and the container will import module `'SAGEMAKER_BASE_PATH>/code/SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `sagemaker.model.FrameworkModel` to create model with required scripts

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating the model from a training job and then using the env variables listed in the question:

```
training_src_file     = "s3://bucket_data_assets/training-src-files.tar.gz"
churn_model = sagemaker_session.create_model_from_job(
    training_job_name=completed_training_job_name, 
    name=None, 
    role=role, image_uri=None, 
    model_data_url=None, 
    env={"SAGEMAKER_DEFAULT_INVOCATIONS_ACCEPT": "text/csv", 
     "SAGEMAKER_USE_NGINX": "True", 
     "SAGEMAKER_WORKER_CLASS_TYPE": "gevent", 
     "SAGEMAKER_KEEP_ALIVE_SEC": "60", 
     "SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20",
     "SAGEMAKER_ENABLE_CLOUDWATCH_METRICS": "false",
     "SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM": "train.py", #the entry point present in training-src-files.tar.gz
     "SAGEMAKER_REGION": "us-east-1",
     "SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY": training_src_file,
    }
```